# How to do a python web API request return a value only if it exists

Tags: python

Im trying to do an api connection, its all ok but when python has to print some values that doesnt exists, it gives me error. When the value exists it goes all ok

code: (using python 3.7)

```
r = requests.get('https://api.csgofloat.com/?url=%s' %floaat, headers={})
data = r.json()
print("Sticker 1: %s" %data['iteminfo']['stickers'][0]['name'])
print("Sticker 2: %s" %data['iteminfo']['stickers'][1]['name'])
print("Sticker 3: %s" %data['iteminfo']['stickers'][2]['name'])
print("Sticker 4: %s" %data['iteminfo']['stickers'][3]['name'])
```

i get all the values when i have all the 4 values, but with only 1 value, it prints the value that exists but then gives error and exit the script, and with no returned value, i only get the error (as said before)

printed error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\Folderzz\Scripts\script.py", line 47, in
>   
>       print("Sticker 1: %s" %data['iteminfo']['stickers'][0]['name']) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It would be much helpful if you could add printed error to your question so it will be easier to analyze the problem.

Comment: ok i'll edit rn

Comment: You should probably just do a loop where you print for i in the range of the length of your data[‘item info’] list.

Comment: Have you tried using loops for printing the values ?

Comment: from your error it seems that list 'stickers' is empty. By this logic it should not print any values at all. Try to print whole json object with `pprint(r.json())` and check what result you get from api.

Comment: [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: thanks guys, solved it using this code: try:
    pprint("   Sticker 1: %s" %data['iteminfo']['stickers'][0]['name'])
except IndexError:
    print("   Sticker 1 not found")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't know how many 'stickers' are coming in, so you should make a loop:

```
i = 0
for sticker in data['iteminfo']['stickers']
   i += 1
   print "Sticker {}: {}".format(i, sticker)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If I solved your doubt, I'll appreciate you to select my answer